# How to display selected data from a row on gridview into another page in ASP NET & VB without using bound fields or template on the gridview?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a page that contains static data populated on rows inside a gridview. When I click edit on this said row, I manage to return the correct id on another page but the data will always show the last entry. *What I mean by this is for example say I want to edit items from row 1, the edit button does redirect me to the setup page however it takes in values from row 3 instead.*

What I want to achieve is when I click edit on a specific row, all data only specific to that row should display in the setup page. Please advice on how I can achieve this. **Not using any template field or bound fields.**

Below is the code behind file of related pages.
This is the page that contains the gridview and the static data.

```
   Public Class Report1
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
            MockProductReport()
        End Sub

        Public Sub MockProductReport()

            Dim dt = New DataTable()
            dt.Columns.Add("Manage")
            dt.Columns.Add("ID", GetType(Integer))
            dt.Columns.Add("Product Name")

            dt.Rows.Add(New Object() {"", 1, "Item1"})
            dt.Rows.Add(New Object() {"", 2, "Item2"})
            dt.Rows.Add(New Object() {"", 3, "Item3"})
            dt.Rows.Add(New Object() {"", 4, "Item4"})
            dt.Rows.Add(New Object() {"", 5, "Item5"})

            gvProductRpt.DataSource = dt
            gvProductRpt.DataBind()

        End Sub

        Protected Sub gvProductRpt_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles gvProductRpt.RowDataBound
            Try
                If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then

                    e.Row.Cells(0).Text =
                        $"<a class='btn btn-primary btn-sm' id='productId' href='{Page.ResolveUrl($"~/Pages/setup.aspx?id={e.Row.Cells(1).Text}")}'><i class='far fa-edit'></i></a>"
                    Dim row As GridViewRow = CType(e.Row.Cells(1).NamingContainer, GridViewRow)
                    Dim text As String = e.Row.Cells(1).Text
                    Session("select") = row
                    Session("value") = text

                End If
            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try

        End Sub
End Class
```

This is the page that contains the form for editing the static data. I just want the data to show up here not necessarily doing the actual 'editing'.

```
 Public Class setup
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If Session("select") Is Nothing Then
            resetThis()
            Literal1.Text = (Session("value")).ToString
        Else
            fillProductInfo()
            Response.Write((Session("value")).ToString)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub resetThis()
        tb1.Text = ""
        tb2.Text = ""
    End Sub

    Private Sub fillProductInfo()
        Try
            Dim e As GridViewRow = CType(Session("select"), GridViewRow)
            Literal1.Text = e.Cells(1).Text
            tb1.Text = e.Cells(2).Text
            tb2.Text = e.Cells(3).Text

        Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub

End Class
```